# How to animate the color of Label In JQuery on specific event?

Tags: jquery, label

I have been trying a lot to change the color of label in JQuery. To the most i could do was to change the color of text inside the label. Please find the below code that i tried.

Label Code:

```
<input type='radio' name='specific_consultant' id='test1' value='no'>No</input>
```

JQuery Function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var button = $('#test1');
    button.click(function() {
        button.css('color', 'FOO');
    });
});
```

But how do i change the color of label on specific events something like [this](http://newsignature.github.io/us-map/#usage-style-options) which displays results in the label?

Comment: On click of button events..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't need be exactly a label. You can use `<div>` and set the style `inline-block` and then set the background color:

css

```
.result{
    background-color: #F00;
    display: inline-block;
    /* transition effect */
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
}
```

html

```
<div class="result"></div>s
```

javascript

```
function setColor(mycolor,defaultcolor,myElement){
    $(myElement).css("background",mycolor);
    //if you need the color back to normal
    //in 1 sec the color will back to normal
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(myElement).css("background",defaultcolor);
    },1000)
}
```

Comment: Be careful with animating `all` since animating is processor heavy. Use `background-color` as the property for transition.

Answer (score 1):

You're JS code is good but you need to add the label to the radio input:

```
<label for="test1">
  <input id="test1" type="radio" value="no">No
</label>
```

Then in your js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var button = $('#test1');
    button.click(function() {
        // Target the <label>
        button.parent().css('color', '#F00');
    });
});
```

Check out this <kbd>[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/UMELIgo/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Simple add this to your css:

```
#test1 {
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease;
}
```

Or you can use [ainmate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function instead **css**.